# Angular Applications Based On Project Templates

Tags: angular, templates, project

I am developing an Angular 7 application that is supposed to be used as a template for future Angular projects.  In other words, once this application is completed, other developers on my team will use this initial application as a template for generating and building their project (preferably from the CLI).  I've seen some similar stuff done in C# and nuget packages, but I haven't necessarily found what I'm looking for with regards to Angular.  Can somebody point me to a good tutorial or example that explains this process in Angular?

UPDATE: I was told elsewhere that I could simply save a project with no dependencies installed and then copy that folder into my new project folder and hit 'npm install'.  But that is not practical for my solution.  I need to be able to notify other developers that when we we build a new application that you would need to do these steps to ensure your application has this starting template for your project.  Would the idea of a library be the solution?  If so, how can I make it a privately published library for only my team to use when creating new projects?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are wanting one angular or modules/components generator.
If the second option, the framework loopback was one sdk that generator angular code, look:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Angular-2-SDK

Comment: I don't know if this is what I'm looking for.  From the link, it says it will "explore your LoopBack Application and will automatically build everything you need to start writing your Angular 2 Applications."  I don't have a LoopBack application, but I already have a working angular application.  I need to take that angular app and have it be a template for future angular applications.